# Create pandas DataFrame from values and list as efficiently as possible

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization

I am looping through a data set and get 2 key values that will be my index and an array of floats. Like so:

```
list_of_lists = []
while True:
            data = file_stream.read(8)
            if not data:
                break
            message_size = int.from_bytes(data, byteorder='little')
            message.ParseFromString(file_stream.read(message_size))
            data_list = [message.key1, message.key2]
            data_list.extend(message.Data)
            list_of_lists.append(data_list)
return pandas.DataFrame.from_records(list_of_lists, index=['key1','key2'], columns=header_list)
```

If I comment out the data_list.extend it runs extremely fast. The extend makes it 50x slower.

I have tried a number of things and can't figure out the optimal way to get the data into a dataframe. Any advice on how to speed this up would appreciated.

Comment: For every iteration of the loop you are fetching all the data from the variable **message** (and this variable doesn't seem to change during the loop). Is that your intent?

Comment: message changes during the loop from this line:

message.ParseFromString(file_stream.read(message_size))

it gets updated to the next row in the file.

Comment: Example data would help.